# Comparing ForeignKey Values In A Form Values Outside The Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm displaying a table. Among the static information on the table I want to insert the checkbox 'read' which is attached to a single User/Book pair.

I cannot figure out how to compare the current `book` in my outter loop with the `book` in my inner `form` loop in order to output the checkbox matching the book.

I have tried many ways of accessing `form.book.id`, `id` being the `book`'s `id` in the DB, not an attribute of the `Book` model.

I think I may have to add an `id` field to my `UserBookData` model.

```
class UserBookData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='user_book_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField()
```

```
{% for book in user.books.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ book.author}}</td>

        {% for item in form %}
            # this -> {% if item.book.id == book.id %}
            <td>{{ item.read }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

```
class UserBookDataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserBookDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        # remove labels
        self.fields['read'].label = ''
```

```
user_book_data_form_set = inlineformset_factory(User, UserBookData, fields=('read',), form=UserBookDataForm, can_delete=False)
formset = user_book_data_form_set(instance=user_model)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show your form definition?

Comment: Sure. I added it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
{% for item in form %}
    {% if item.instance.book.id == book.id %}
        {{ item.read }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```